# Visual Studio 2010 MSDN Licensing?

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know how licensing work for Visual Studio 2010 from MSDN? I noticed it doesn't require a key. Does that mean that I can install it on multiple computers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the source :) [MSDN Subscription Software Use Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx):

> MSDN subscriptions are licensed on a per-user basis.  One person can use the software to design, develop, test, or demonstrate his or her programs on any number of devices.  Each person who uses the software this way needs a license.

So yes, as long as you're the one using it, it may be on multiple computers.  Two different Microsoft licensing reps have confirmed this for me over the years, and it was a conscious decision since *many* developers have multiple machines.  This applies to [other MSDN downloads as well](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products), Windows 7, Windows Server, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is "pre-pidded", which means the key is baked in. You can install it on any computer you like, but that doesn't mean you should - you still have to abide by the licence agreement imposed by your subscription.

Answer (score 1):

By itself, this does not mean that you have a license for multiple computers. Quite a few Microsoft products have built-in license keys for certain license types which allow only a single installation. Look at your license agreement. If it's still unclear, call Microsoft or ask a lawyer.